Snap refresh returns an error in Ubuntu 22.04
When I try to do snap refresh, I am getting the following error:
sudo snap refresh
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Fetch and check assertions for snap "snapd" (21759) (cannot verify snap "snapd", no matching signatures found)

Could not find anything related to this error. Any help is welcome.
snap version
snap    2.62+22.04
snapd   2.62+22.04
series  16
ubuntu  22.04
kernel  6.5.0-35-generic



snap list --all
Name                       Version           Rev    Tracking         Publisher   Notes
bare                       1.0               5      latest/stable    canonical✓  base
core                       16-2.61.2         16928  latest/stable    canonical✓  core
core22                     20240111          1122   latest/stable    canonical✓  base,disabled
core22                     20240408          1380   latest/stable    canonical✓  base
firefox                    126.0.1-1         4336   latest/stable/…  mozilla✓    -
firefox                    123.0-3           3836   latest/stable/…  mozilla✓    disabled
gnome-42-2204              0+git.510a601     176    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gnome-42-2204              0+git.ff35a85     141    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
gtk-common-themes          0.1-81-g442e511   1535   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
gtk2-common-themes         0.1               13     latest/stable    canonical✓  -
p7zip-desktop              16.02.2           220    latest/stable    ernytech    -
snap-store                 41.3-77-g7dc86c8  1113   latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -
snap-store                 41.3-71-g709398e  959    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
snapd                      2.61.1            20671  latest/stable    canonical✓  snapd
snapd-desktop-integration  0.9               83     latest/stable/…  canonical✓  disabled
snapd-desktop-integration  0.9               157    latest/stable/…  canonical✓  -


Please edit your question and add the output of the command snap list --all.

may be related? https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/solution-to-an-issue-encountered-when-some-snaps-are-not-found/28887
